# Html2pdf not working with cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded a power bi report into my webpage. I want to convert the div containing this iframe into PDF. I have set iframe's `sandbox` property to `allow-same-origin allow-scripts`.

```
report.on('rendered', function (event) {
   $("#reportContainer > iframe").attr('sandbox', 'allow-same-origin allow-scripts');
});

html2canvas(document.getElementById('reportContainer'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            },
            width: 300,
            height: 300
});
```

But still the iframe is coming as blank webpage. Why this is happening?

Comment: Because you can't access cross-domain content, allow-same-origin does not disable that mechanism. If it did any 3rd party site could scrape any user's data from the target site simply by having an iframe with that attribute

Comment: @Patrick Evans then what should I do in this case. I want to convert the iframe to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Now, it's possible to export the Power BI embedded report to pdf using the [ExportToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file) Rest API.

Refer [Export Power BI embedded Report to pdf](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to) documentation for more details.

Refer to Sample [gist file](https://gist.github.com/KotanaSai21/63e585284b1f5045ef2a154b76ea380f) implemented in React.